# Cassandra running out of memory (heap space)

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

We are experimenting a bit with Cassandra lately (version 1.0.7) and we seem to have some problems with memory. We use EC2 as our test environment and we have three nodes with 3.7G of memory and 1 core @ 2.4G, all running Ubuntu server 11.10.

The problem is that the node we hit from our thrift interface dies regularly (approximately after we store 2-2.5G of data). Error message: OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space and according to the log it in fact used all of the allocated memory.

The nodes are under relatively constant load and store about 2000-4000 row keys a minute, which are batched through the Trift interface in 10-30 row keys at once (with about 50 columns each). The number of reads is very low with around 1000-2000 a day and only requesting the data of a single row key. The is currently only one used column family.

The initial thought was that something was wrong in the cassandra-env.sh file. So, we specified the variables 'system_memory_in_mb' (3760) and the 'system_cpu_cores' (1) according to our nodes' specification. We also changed the 'MAX_HEAP_SIZE' to 2G and the 'HEAP_NEWSIZE' to 200M (we think the second is related to the Garbage Collection). Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue and the node we hit via thrift keeps on dying regularly.

In case you find this useful, swap is off and unevictable memory seems to be very high on all 3 servers (2.3GB, we usually observe the amount of unevictable memory on other Linux servers of around 0-16KB) (We are not quite sure how the unevictable memory ties into Cassandra, its just something we observed while looking into the problem). The CPU is pretty much idle the entire time. The heap memory is clearly being reduced once in a while according to nodetool, but obviously grows over the limit as time goes by.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you running?  Also, you might cross-post this to the Cassandra users list, as it is a pretty active spot to get advice on things like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's 1.0.7. I updated the question to show the version of Cassandra we are running. I will search for the Cassandra users list as well. Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable caching?  The row cache can really kill your memory.  Also, did you manually specify commit log thresholds or change any of the memory stuff in the cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Also, the unevictable memory is because Cassandra calls mlockall on the java heap so if swap isn't off, it still won't be swapped out.

Answer (score 3):

cassandra-env.sh defaults are perfect for almost all workloads, so until you know why this is happening best to put them back to their defaults or you may be making things worse without realizing.

I see concurrent reads and writes of 2k/sec/node on our cluster, so 2k-4k writes per minute is very little, although the fact that it's only the node accepting your connections that is dying is a little strange.

If you connect your app to the thrift endpoint on one of the other nodes is it then that one that dies?
Client connections use memory so might be worth double checking you're not connecting too many at a time. "*netstat -A inet | grep 9160*" on the dying cassandra node should tell you how many client connections you have. Depending heavily on your application you'd expect 10s or 100s rather than 1000s.

What do the writes look like?
Are you writing the same row keys repeatedly and if so are you appending new column names or overwriting the same ones?
How big is each write? Anything else you can tell me?
If you're overwriting the same column names in the same row keys constantly compaction may be struggling.
If you're appending new column names to the same row keys constantly you might be growing your rows too large to fit into memory.

the output of "nodetool -h localhost tpstats" on the dying node might also give some clues as to where you're falling down. Anything constantly pending is probably bad news, especially at such a low write rate.

If you're going to use cassandra in production you should get graphing of the internals to better understand what's going on. jmxtrans and graphite should be your new best friends.

Comment: Could you share a few key settings for the use case describeb by the question?

Answer (score 2):

There are some things you can try tweaking.  First make sure you dont have row caching on your column family.  Also worth while checking the log for errors and tpstats incase something died due to an error and something is getting backed up in a queue.  The stack trace of the exception could be meaningful too since there are actually different types of OOMs that could just mean kernel tweaks.

If your just using too much memory per node then you want for the size of your data set try checking the cfstats, you can identify roughly how much space is spent on bloom filters.  As you have more rows in a CF this can get linearly larger and is part of the base minimum memory your nodes are going to require.

```
nodetool cfstats | grep Bloom.*Used | awk '{ SUM += $5} END { print SUM " bytes" }'
```

Since you dont read very often you can probably increase the false positive rate on them.  Each SSTable has a bloom filter it uses to check if a row exists in it or not.  You can change with cqlsh

```
ALTER TABLE MyColumnFamily WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1;
```

After that call an upgrade on that CF (this will be slow) per node

```
nodetool upgradesstables MyKeyspace MyColumnFamily
```

There are consequences to this where reads may take longer since there is a 10%-ish (the .1) chance it will check SSTables for rows that dont exist in it, resulting in extra disk seeks.

Another major memory sink if you have column families with large amount of rows is the sampling rate of the index.  This can be modified per node level in the cassandra.yaml

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/configuration/node_configuration#index-interval

If you have it set up to take heap dumps on OOM (-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError on by default  I believe) there should be some heap dumps available in the /var/lib/cassandra/data directory.  You can open these up in visualvm or whatever tool you like to identify what part of the heaps is where.

Comment: Update for Cassandra 2.0: `nodetool cfstats | grep "Bloom.*used" | awk '{ SUM += $6} END { print SUM " bytes" }'`